# Vehicle Turning Left or Right

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coordinate-systems

I have the $(x,y)$ positions of a vehicle. How can I determine if the vehicle is turning left or right?

Note: I want the answer to be independent of whether the vehicle is in reverse gear or not. Does that make sense?

Currently, I do this finding the change in coordinates and then taking the 2D cross product (which gives you $z$-th component) and find if this is positive or negative. Basically, I try to relate it to the right-hand rule, but then how do I know if the vehicle is not turning? I think I need a holistic/general approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left or right depends if you are going forward or backwards. Suppose that you have three points $P_{1,2,3}$, at times $t_{1,2,3}$. The initial direction is given by moving from $P_1$ to $P_2$. Let's say I move forward. Then $P_3$ can be on the left, so you need to turn to the left. If you go in reverse from $P_1$ to $P_2$, then $P_3$ is going to be on the right hand side, so you need to turn to the right.

Therefore there is no solution for your problem, unless you specify the forward/backward choice.

Suppose that we choose to move forward. How do we know if we turn left or right? A simple way is to use vector product. For that, we use 3D vectors, with the third component $0$. then we have $$\vec v_1=\vec P_2-\vec P_1=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,0)$$ and similarly $$\vec v_2=\vec P_3-\vec P_2=(x_3-x_2,y_3-y_2,0)$$
Using the [matrix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation), you can see that $$\vec v_1\times\vec v_2=[(x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_2)-(x_3-x_2)(y_2-y_1)]\hat z$$
Now if you use the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition) of the cross product on wikipedia, you can see that the sign of the above expression is the same as the sign of the angle. That means that if $(x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_2)-(x_3-x_2)(y_2-y_1)>0$ then the car turns in positive trigonometric direction, which is left. If the expression is negative, you turn to the right. If the expression is $0$, you either stopped, or you continue moving in the original direction (either forward or backward). To distinguish between these two, use the scalar product.

Comment: Ok, so I have an algorithm that specifies if I am going forward or reverse. It is just going to be more of a pain to implement. How do I, mathematically, find out if the vehicle is turning left or right?

Comment: I will add to my solution

Comment: Sounds good, I appreciate all your help!

Comment: See if it's clear now. Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Ok, that is one case. Would backward just be the exact opposite of that case? That is, <0 means right and >0 means left? Also, how to determine if I am going left or right if I only have two points and go from one to the other. Meaning if I turn this into an array, I cannot get an indicator (left, right or forward/backward) for the second point.

Comment: Backward is just opposite. If you have only two points it does not make sense to say you go left or right, unless you have an original reference frame. If I go from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ is that left or right? Depends. For example, say I came from $(-1,0)$ or from $(0,-1)$. One is left, the other is right.

Comment: Great. I understand now :) Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure its not the opposite? https://algorithmtutor.com/Computational-Geometry/Determining-if-two-consecutive-segments-turn-left-or-right/ this says >0 is right.

Comment: @EAB note that in their `direction` function, the order of cross product terms is reversed. This yields a change in sign since $\vec v_1\times\vec v_2=-\vec v_2\times\vec v_1$